# AppDelegate integration of Typhoon with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, typhoon

I've been using Typhoon with AppDelegate integration in Swift 3 without any problems but since updating to Swift 4 and Xcode 9 I'm having an issue where `initialAssemblies()` is never called.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func initialAssemblies() -> NSArray {
    return [SharedComponentsAssembly.self,
            ViewControllersAssembly.self]
}
```

Previously in Swift 3, Xcode 8: `initialAssemblies()` was called before `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Now in **Swift 4, Xcode 9**: `initialAssemblies()` is never called

I've looked in the [Activating Assemblies](https://github.com/appsquickly/typhoon/wiki/activating-assemblies) guide from Typhoon wiki but couldn't find the solution. 
For now I'm using plist integration as a workaround but I'd prefer to use the AppDelegate integration.

If anyone has successfully used the AppDelegate integration with Swift 4 please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add "@objc" specifier? 
Like that

```
@objc func initialAssemblies() -> [Any] {
    return [SharedComponentsAssembly.self,
            ViewControllersAssembly.self]
}
```

I've checked and this method gets called in my case.